# In python, how to have a 'run' subpackage in a directory?

Tags: python, import, package

I would prefer to have the structure to look like:

```
Overall_Package/

__init__.py

run_package/{

__init__.py
run__subpackage1.py
run_subpackage2.py
run_subpackage3.py
...
}

code package/ {

Basic_code_package_that_is_used_in_many_if_not_all_the_sub_packages
Sub_package1
subpackage2
....
}
```

I cannot use relative imports as they are in the same overall package, but I need a structure similar to this for easy downloading.

Comment: Thanks, Roman Bodnarchuk, for editing this to make it readable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, if the directory above `Overall_Package` is in your `PYTHONPATH`, then you can use absolute imports in your modules, e.g. `import Overall_Package.code_package.subpackage2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I follow your question and what is it exactly you want. Do you need to distribute this and would like it to have that structure? If so you can always use [setuptools](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) or [distutils](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial) and install your package with it's structure to python's site-packages directory.

Comment: No, this is not for distribution. However, I need to install this on several computers and nevertheless wants this structure.

Comment: Well even if it's not for distribution using the above and making a setup.py will make installing it easier. Or you could just edit your PYTHONPATH to add your Overall_Package and use the solution Nicola suggested.

Comment: That means I will have to change every run_file to have over_allpackage appended to pythonpath?

Comment: Well since you will only be installing in a few machines you could just copy directory to some location, say: `/Users/Shared/Top_Package`, then edit `bash_profile` with `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/Shared/Top_Package` and that's it.